Trouble Setting Access Point 2.4GHz Orange Pi Zero 2
I'm setting up a WiFi Access Point using bridge mode. I successfully configured the bridge mode and it's working. Then, I managed to set up the WiFi Access Point for 5GHz as well. But why did I fail when setting it up for 2.4 GHz?
Trouble:

Visible after restart, then after 1-2 minuter, WiFi AP not visible
After restart, i cant access my orange pi with ssh or VNC, but can access with HDMI

This my configuration:
sudo nano /etc/hostapd.conf

Script:
#
# orangepi hostapd configuration example
#
# nl80211 mode
#

ssid=HIBOBGATEWAY
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=6  # Set to a common 2.4GHz channel (1-13)
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211

logger_syslog=0
logger_syslog_level=0
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
preamble=1

wpa_psk=66eb31d2b48d19ba216f2e50c6831ee11be98e2fa3a8075e30b866f4a5ccda27
wpa_passphrase=6666666666
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0

### IEEE 802.11n
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][HT40+]
country_code=ID
ieee80211d=1
### IEEE 802.11n

### IEEE 802.11a
#hw_mode=a
### IEEE 802.11a

### IEEE 802.11ac
#ieee80211ac=1
#vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][SHORT-GI-80][TX-STBC-2BY1][RX-STBC-1][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP3]
#vht_oper_chwidth=1
#vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
### IEEE 802.11ac

# controlling enabled
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

For bridge setting:
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Script
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# Network is managed by Network manager
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
#wireless power off

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.6.57
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.6.254
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
bridge_fd 0
bridge_stp off
Copy code

Can you help me?
Linux Kernel: Linux 4.9.170-sun50iw9
Distro: UBUNTU Bionic
Hardware: Orange-Pi Zero 2
